# While Creating Userform I'm facing some errors

Tags: vba

Hi I'm Uma Mahesh from Vijayawada, I am trying to create a Employee UserForm.

In that I'm trying to Load Country Mobile Code by Selecting Country.

I created a Excel Workbook with three Sheets named as 1. Raw Data, 2. Home, 3. Filled Data

I loaded Country Names with Mobile Codes in Raw Data and hided it and I want Data to be filled in Home Sheet or Filled Data Sheet

Now I'm in Home Sheet and trying to fill data, but it is showing runtime error, but when I'm in Raw Data Sheet and trying to fill data, there is no error appearing.

How to resolve it?

Will any one please respond??

Following is my code

```
Dim CC2 As Long, i as Long
**CC2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1", Range("a1").End(xlDown)).Cells.Count**

For i = 1 To CC2
        If Cmb1.Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value Then
            Sheets("Sheet2").Range("a1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value
        End If
Next i
```

The above is my code and the error showing in line 2

Thank you

Uma Mahesh

Comment: This is probably because your code doesn't specify the worksheet and therefore uses the ActiveSheet, but unless you show your code and tell the exact error you get and at which statement it appears, how can we know

Comment: Please don't post code in a comment. Edit your question and put it there - and don't forget to format it as code so that it is readable

Comment: To format code as code, mark the code and press the button with the curly brackets `{}`

Comment: The `Range("a1")`-part of your statement is not qualified, so VBA will assume that you want to access the active sheet.

Comment: before that i specified the sheet name

Comment: That doesn't matter. `Range` is not a function, it is a method of a sheet. And if you don't specify the sheet, VBA assume ActiveSheet. SO is full with questions about that.

Answer (score 0):

FunThomas is right. Try activating the sheet when performing your code.
Example.

```
Worksheets("TestSh").Activate 'Performe your code here and then just activate the next sheet. Just keep in mind that if you use the name of the sheet in Excel, someone could change it in your workbook and mess up your code.
```

Different methods to activate a sheet.

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Worksheets("1").Activate
```

I custom name my sheets in the Properties Window, it makes it easier, and if someone changes the name or the order of the sheets, it won't mess up my code.
For example, you could name your sheets ShOriginal and ShNew, so its neater:

```
ShOriginal.Activate
ShNew.Activate
```

Here's a site that explains it better:
https://analysistabs.com/vba-code/worksheet/m/activate/

Let us know if we were able to help you!

Comment: No!  **Never use activate**!! Specify the worksheet you want to work with!!!

Comment: What? In cases where the macro runs in more than one sheet, even if you specify the workheet, named in the properties window and all, the macro needs to have the sheet activated... you can't perform it otherwise.

Comment: Sure you can. Don't know why you think you can't